# Spring Security Error: "UnsatisfiedDependencyException" with message about "setFilterChains"

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I'm encountering an issue while working with Spring Security, and I'm having trouble resolving it. The error message I'm getting is:
`org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'configureSecurity' defined in class path resource [com/project/CarDB/Config/SecurityConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'configureSecurity' threw exception with message: This method cannot decide whether these patterns are Spring MVC patterns or not. If this endpoint is a Spring MVC endpoint, please use requestMatchers(MvcRequestMatcher); otherwise, please use requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher).`
Here's a portion of my SecurityConfig class where I define the security configurations:

```
package com.project.CarDB.Config;

import com.project.CarDB.service.UserDetailServiceImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailServiceImpl userDetailsService;
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService (BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder){
        InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();

        manager.createUser(
                User.withUsername("user").password(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode("userPass")).roles("USER").build()
        );

        manager.createUser(
                User.withUsername("admin").password(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode("adminPass")).roles("ADMIN").build()
        );

        return manager;
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }


    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
        return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
    }


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain configureSecurity(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()  // Use mvcMatchers for Spring MVC patterns
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                );

        return http.build();
    }



}
```

I believe the error is related to the configureSecurity method, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Can someone please help me understand what's causing this error and how to resolve it? Thank you in advance!

(Additional code snippets such as LoginController and JwtService were provided in the original post for context.)

```
package com.project.CarDB.web;

import com.project.CarDB.Domain.Account.AccountCredentials;
import com.project.CarDB.service.JwtService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    JwtService jwtService;

    @Autowired AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> getToken (@RequestBody AccountCredentials accountCredentials){
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken credentials = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(accountCredentials.getUserName(), accountCredentials.getPassword());

        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(credentials);

        // GENERATE TOKENS
        String jwts = jwtService.getToken(authentication.getName());

        //BUILD RESPONSE WITH THE GENERATED TOKEN
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "BEARER " + jwts)
                .header(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_EXPOSE_HEADERS, "Authorization")
                .build();
    }
}
```

```
package com.project.CarDB.service;


import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys;
import java.security.Key;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.util.Date;

@Component
public class JwtService {

    static final long EXPIRATIONTIME = 86400000; // 1 day in ms
    static final String PREFIX = "Bearer";
    static final Key key = Keys.secretKeyFor(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256);

    public String getToken(String username) {
        String token = Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(username)
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + EXPIRATIONTIME))
                .signWith(key)
                .compact();
        return token;
    }


    public String getAuthUser(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String token = request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);

        if (token != null) {
            String user = Jwts.parserBuilder()
                    .setSigningKey(key)
                    .build()
                    .parseClaimsJws(token.replace(PREFIX, ""))
                    .getBody()
                    .getSubject();

            if (user != null)
                return user;
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

I tried modifying both the configureSecurity method and other methods within the code, but after a day of searching for a solution, I gave up. If I remove the SecurityFilterChain, my application runs without errors.

I have conducted further investigations and noticed that only when I use: `http.authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll();`, any authorization of the form `.authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("")` fails to work.

However, when I write:

```
http.csrf().disable().cors().and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

http.formLogin().and().httpBasic();
return http.build();
```

My application runs, but the POST method I use in `LoginController` doesn't function as expected.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

You could try using either MvcRequestMatcher or AntPathRequestMatcher like the following, depending on if you need Spring mvc paths or ant path patterns

```
.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login", "POST")).permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/util/matcher/AntPathRequestMatcher.html